# Removing data from list inside two for loops

Tags: python, python-3.x, computer-vision, computational-geometry

I have a data structure Line whose outline is :

```
class Line :
    x1
    y1
    x2
    y2
    m
    c
    id
    # other functions pertaining to the class
```

In the main loop I have a list of lines which are already populated at this point.

What I want to do is consolidate lines which have m and c values very close so I get single line instead of multiple lines from detection

```
for line1 in allLines:
    consolidateLines = []
    for line2 in allLines:
        if line1.id() == line2.id():
            continue;
        if abs(line1.m() - line2.m()) < SomeValue:
            if abs(line1.c() - line2.c()) < someOtherValue:
                consolidateLines.append(line2);
    consolidateLines.append(line1);
    # I want to remove all the lines in consolidatedLines. 
    # But since this is already in the loop, that is a problem. 
    # How do I accomplish this.
```

Explaining the problem :
I have a list of lines. Since these lines are detected using a computer vision algorithm (Hough Transforms), some of the lines are very close to each other. That is not ideal. So I am trying to consolidate all the lines that are very close and have close orientation. If one line is represented by y=mx + c, i'm trying to :

> 1. consolidate all lines (may have 5 lines which are close by) within the list with nearly same values of m and c and get one line for those.
> 2. remove all the consolidated lines
> 3. add the new line that i get in the list.

Comment: this: `for abs(line1.c() - line2.c()) < someOtherValue:` appears to be an error.  It is unclear to me what this is trying to do.

Comment: @StephenRauch : Yep. sorry that was my bad !

Comment: Sorry, I find it difficult to comprehend what you're trying to do. Can you explain it simply? You have AllLines with `Line` Objects in it. What do you wish to do?

Comment: @iTayb: Added the explanation. Hope that makes it clearer

Answer (score 1):

To remove duplicates from a list you basically need to compare every element with every other element from the list. In order to not compare twice you need to start the second loop at the position of the first loop + 1.

The following code does that, and if it finds a duplicate skips the first of the two values (`break`) command:

```
consolidateLines = []
for i, line1 in enumerate(allLines):
    for j, line2 in enumerate(allLines[i+1:]):
        if abs(line1.m() - line2.m()) < SomeValue and 
           abs(line1.c() - line2.c()) < someOtherValue:
                break # found a duplicate later in the list, skipping first occurrence
    else:
        # no duplicagte found -> add to list
        consolidateLines.append(line1);
```

Comment: Doesn't this only find one line that is close to the other ? What if I have 5 lines which are close by and i want to consolidate all of them ?

Comment: No, it will check every pair. Let's say you have 4 items 1,2,3,4 then it will compare 1-2, 1-3, 1-4, 2-3, 2-4, 3-4

Comment: you may add a `print(line1, line2)` into the inner for loop to understand what's going on

Comment: (100, 100, 200, 200);
(100, 100, 200, 201);
(100, 100, 200, 199);
(100, 100, 200, 100);
(100, 100, 200, 101);
(100, 100, 200, 99.9);
(100, 100, 200, 100.1);

So I tried with these lines as (x1, y1, x2, y2) values. I expected only 2 outputs. The output is :
(100 ,  100 ,  200 ,  199)
(100 ,  100 ,  200 ,  100)
(100 ,  100 ,  200 ,  99.9)
The last two should have been consolidated

Comment: @navderm what's the value of `SomeValue` and `someOtherValue`? Then I could try to reproduce

Comment: also: in your question you said you want to compare the values of the functions `m()` and `c()`, but now you're posting only x1,x2,y1,y2. I'm confused

Comment: @hansaplast: Hey. Nope. So the input is (x1, y1, x2, y2). Internally the values of m, c, length are updated at construction. The output is (x1, y1, x2, y2) because that's how it'll be drawn. (x1, y1, x2, y2, m, c, length ) are persisted within the line data structure.

Comment: @hansaplast: The values of threshold for m comparison as represented by math.degrees(m2 - m1) is 5 and for (c2 - c1) is 50.

Comment: @navderm if you'd like you can post the relevant code to gist.github.com and I'll have a look on what the problem could be

Comment: @hansaplast:   
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a3fedd60d83646ec16983886b2bf6dd6

Comment: @hansaplast : Take a look at consolidateLines2(). Not consolidateLines()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133150/discussion-between-hansaplast-and-navderm).